# aws cli Image rrun from docker compose and it's shutdon after one second

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-cli

I tried to run aws cli image from amazon from docker-compose.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    web:
        image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
        stdin_open: true # equivalent of -i
        tty: true        # equivalent of -t
        deploy:
          mode: replicated
          replicas: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              cpus: "2"
              memory: 2048M
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
            delay: 5s
            max_attempts: 3
            window: 120s
        environment:
          - HTTP_PROXY=http://ipadresses:port
          - HTTPS_PROXY=https://ipadresses:port
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
```

After one second, the image stops running immediately. I looked for the official documentation from amazon but I cannot find an answer to my question: why it's stop so quickely Could someone please help me understand this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`amazon/aws-cli:latest` is a docker image that provides only the aws command as starting command, which means, if you don't override the command executed by docker the container will execute `aws` command and stop the execution.

To execute commands against `aws` using that docker image you need to provide your command e.g. in this compose file I'm executing `aws help` by adding `command: help` to the file.

```
    version: '3.1'
services:
    web:
        image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
        stdin_open: true # equivalent of -i
        tty: true        # equivalent of -t
        command: help
        deploy:
          mode: replicated
          replicas: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              cpus: "2"
              memory: 2048M
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
            delay: 5s
            max_attempts: 3
            window: 120s
        environment:
          - HTTP_PROXY=http://ipadresses:port
          - HTTPS_PROXY=https://ipadresses:port
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
```

Alternatively you could override `entrypoint` to force the container to stay alive, so afterwards you can exec commands against your container e.g

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    web:
        image: amazon/aws-cli:latest
        stdin_open: true # equivalent of -i
        tty: true        # equivalent of -t
        entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
        deploy:
          mode: replicated
          replicas: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              cpus: "2"
              memory: 2048M
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
            delay: 5s
            max_attempts: 3
            window: 120s
        environment:
          - HTTP_PROXY=http://ipadresses:port
          - HTTPS_PROXY=https://ipadresses:port
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
```

After you run this compose file (in another terminal) you can inspect the name of the created container with `docker ps` and then execute commands against that using `docker exec -it <your_container_name> aws help` (note that in this case I'm sending the command `aws help` to the running container)